# Python Regex search() and match()

Tags: python-2.7

What is the difference between Python Regex match() and search().

I've read the documentation (current documentation), but I never seem to remember it. I keep having to look it up and re-learn it. I'm hoping that someone will answer it clearly with examples so that (perhaps) it will stick in my head. Or at least I'll have a better place to return with my question and it will take less time to re-learn it.

Comment: Just to be clear this is more or less the exact duplicate.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help!